# How can I mix vertically-centered elements with different font sizes and retain consistent line height?

Tags: html, css

When you mix font-sizes of elements with `vertical-align: middle` inside of a container, the container's height can be larger than the line-height or height of either individual element. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89bcs62y/11/):

```css
body {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.smaller {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="why-not-twenty-px">
    containing div has height <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> of 21px, not 20px
  </div>
  <div class="why-not-sixty-px">
    containing div has height of 61 px, not 60px multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the two containing divs are 21px and 61px instead of 20px and 60px.

How can I retain a container height that is a multiple of the line-height when mixing in an element like `.smaller`? `.smaller` must be vertically centered on the line. Ideally, any solution would only involve CSS changes to `.smaller`.

Comment: Bounty coming in 2 days, so save this :D

Comment: Apologies for offering the bounty so late, I kind of forgot I had asked this!

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you mean by "centered on the line"? The center of a `.smaller` letter aligns with the center of a regular letter? And no matter what you want it's definitely not `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[§10.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) explains how the height of the line boxes is calculated:

> As described in the section on [inline formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting), user
>   agents flow inline-level boxes into a vertical stack of [line
>   boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box). The height of a line box is determined as follows:

1. > The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated.
   >   [...] For inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'

   Since `.smaller` inherits `line-height: 20px` and is an [inline box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-box) (i.e. non-replaced with `display: inline`), its height is `20px`
2. > The inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their
   >   ['vertical-align'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property.

   `.smaller` has [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)`: middle`, which means

   > Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent
   >   box plus half the x-height of the parent.
3. > The line box height is the distance between the uppermost box top and
   >   the lowermost box bottom.

So both the text and `.smaller` have a height of `20px`, but they have different alignment. Therefore, the line box grows:

[image]

Then, as other answers explain, a way to solve the problem is reducing `.smaller`'s `line-height`:

[image]

However, there is an alternative solution, without modifying `line-height`: negative margins can be added to prevent `.smaller` from increasing the height of the line box.

As quoted above, the height of an inline box is its `line-height`, so to make the margins work, `display: inline-block` is also needed:

> The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For
>   [...] inline-block elements [...] this is the height of their margin
>   box.

Note this solution won't break the alignment, because since `.smaller` has `vartical-align: middle`, if we use the same amount in `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, it will remain centered.

[image]

To summarize, you can use this code:

```css
.smaller {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -1em 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.smaller {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="why-not-twenty-px">
    nor<span class="smaller">&bull;</span>mal
  </div>
  <div class="why-not-sixty-px">
    multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline
    multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha, I am just totally misunderstanding what he is asking then.  My fault.

Comment: Oh, my great edit is too late for the bounty. Well, I have learned a lot doing it.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer and your technique ended up being more generically applicable. Shame I can't award a second bounty.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this by making the `line-height` relative to the `font-size`, instead of a fixed one.

```
body {
    line-height: 1.4285;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

will fix the issue of the extra pixels on the containers.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/b5zgpktj/

---

To only affect the `.smaller` element you can give it a `line-height` of 1

```
.smaller
{
    line-height:1;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/b5zgpktj/1/

Comment: The weird thing about this is that the line-height doesnt need to have a value of 1. The solution still seems to work if the line-height is set to 0 or normal. Clearly the issue resides in the way that the leading for the text is calculated for an element that is vertically aligned and somehow line height offsets the issue related to the vertical alignment calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Put `line-height: 100%` or `line-height: 1` (preffered) on `.smaller` element. Also, if you put `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom` without changing line-height containers would be 20px and 60px.

By making line-height computed from actual font-size or ensuring element top/bottom is aligned with parent, height remains same (this assumes your child element always has smaller font-size than parent). Otherwise you inherit 20px fixed line-height which adds to parent total height when parent and child boxes are not aligned (this happens when font-size differs and vertical-align is anything than top/bottom, including `middle` or default `baseline` value).

```css
body {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.smaller {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1 // or 100% 
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="why-not-twenty-px">
    containing div has height <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> of 21px, not 20px
  </div>
  <div class="why-not-sixty-px">
    containing div has height of 61 px, not 60px multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 2):

The container div is taking a height of 21px because the span.smaller element is having a line-height of 20px. The siblings of span element also have a line height of 20px. You need to understand that line-height property is used while calculating the vertical-align property. Now if you want to apply "vertical-align: middle" to the span.smaller change its line-height to something smaller than their siblings line-height i.e. 20px, or else it will try to center the span.smaller element with respect to its siblings. Since span.smaller line-height is also 20px it will cause the container to have more height.

For example

```
    <div class="body">
 <div class="why-not-twenty-px">
    containing div has height 
     <span class="smaller"> &bull;</span> 
     of 21px, not 20px
  </div>
<div class="abcd">
    <span>The same problem can </span>
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;color:grey;"> be             replicated </span> 
    <span> while using tags with same font-size and line-height, height will be 21px</span>
  </div>
<div class="why-not-sixty-px">
containing div has height of 61 px, not 60px multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline <span class="smaller">&bull;</span> multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline multiline
```

CSS

```
    body
    {
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .smaller
    {
        font-size: 12px;/*I prefer to use px over em, same as 0.9em*/
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 12px;/*use any smaller line height compared to         siblings*/
    }
    .abcd span{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

OR Please follow this link https://jsfiddle.net/osha90/meeLL0u9/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
line-height: 1em;
```

add this style to `.smaller` and bullet will get vertically aligned to center.