# <small> tag destroys vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I have set up vertical alignment using the same value line-height, vertical margins and paddings, but when there is a smaller element, like the `<small>` tag, inside the flow, it ruins for some pixels the vertical rhythm, I can solve adding vertical-align:top/bottom but the element is not aligned with the other text, U can add `display:inline-block` and `transform:translateY(1px)` to solve the other issue but this is not an elegant solution. Is there some other solutions? And I'm wondering why smaller texts work like that.

I linked a photo to make more clear.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPvm.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide some code and at best a fiddle.

Comment: We can't answer if you don't provide the code. It might be a duplicate of [How can I mix vertically-centered elements with different font sizes and retain consistent line height?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27638527/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work without breaking vertical alignment:

```
p small {
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your lines of text to always have the same height, so they match your background, use [`line-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property.