# Why line-height of code tag is "broken"?

Tags: css

Using this HTML and CSS:

```css
code {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 2px 7px;
  line-height: 24px; /* this doesn't seem to do anything, but added anyway */
}

p {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p>test 1</p>
<p>test <code>2</code></p>
```

The height of the first paragraph is 24px while the height of the second is 25px, even if both have the same line-height and computed line-height value (24px).

If you add `line-height: normal;` to the `<code>` tag, the problem is fixed.

Why?

The line-height and computed line-height is the same in both cases. Why different height and why code needs to have line-height:normal? Isn't that the default already?

EDIT: Even if giving `line-height: 24px` to the `<code>` tag, that computes a height of 25px anyway.

Comment: Which browser and version? Can't reproduce with Chrome 51.

Comment: Huh, with the latest 51 beta I *can* reproduce this...

Comment: I see it too.  I'm on 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) for Mac OS X 10.11.4.  `font-family: monospace` is the only system style applied.  It's also interesting to note that crazy font families like `font-family: cursive` drastically affect `line-height` event when it's explicitly set to `24px`.

Comment: That depends on the font used by `code`. If it has a different descender than the font of the surrounding p, this happens.

Comment: I added a note to the question about line-height:24px still gives me height of 25px in the paragraph

Comment: @MrLister and what's the reason for this values?

Comment: @FelixSanz Because the total line height of a line with different fonts is the largest descender + the largest ascender. So you get discrepancies if those differ. I can make a drawing if you want...

Comment: it depends on the `font-family` applied.

Comment: @MrLister If i have understand fine, that still doesn't explain why the height is 25px. You talking about baselines or something like that? Excuse me if this seems so simple :D

Comment: I posted it an an answer, with a drawing I hope illuminates things.

Comment: Guys, can we come up with a better title and tags for this question so it could be useful in future?

Comment: Related: [How can I mix vertically-centered elements with different font sizes and retain consistent line height?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27638527/1529630)

Comment: @ItayGrudev Sure, can you suggest please? My english is not so good. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two different fonts with different metrics in one line, the total height might not be the same height as either of the fonts, even if they have the same height in pixels.

The thing is, the fonts are positioned on the baseline, so if one font has a larger descender (and a smaller ascender), this is what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the total height is larger than the black rectangles, even if those rectangles have the same height!

As for the `line-height` property, remember that this property is inherited.
So if you set a value of `24px` on the `p`, the `code` also gets the line height of 24. But if you then explicitly reset the value for `code` to `normal`, the line height for `code` is reset to 1.2 times the font size.
So then the line height for `code` (and therefore the height) is 19 pixels, and it no longer influences the total height of the `p`.

[image]

Comment: Why line-height:normal fixes it?

Comment: Because it reduces the total height of the `code`. I've added more explanation; hope this helps!